# SAS- Calculate Top Percent of Population

Tags: sas, statistics, percentage, proc-sql

I am trying to seek some validation, this may be trivial for most but I am by no means an expert at statistics.  I am trying to select patients in the top 1% based on a score within each drug and location.  The data would look something like this (on a much larger scale):

```
Patient    drug    place    score
John         a      TX        12
Steven       a      TX        10 
Jim          B      TX        9
Sara         B      TX        4   
Tony         B      TX        2
Megan        a      OK        20
Tom          a      OK        10
Phil         B      OK        9 
Karen        B      OK        2
```

The code snipit I have written to calculate those top 1% patients is as follows:
proc sql;

```
create table example as 
select *,
score/avg(score) as test_measure
from prior_table
group by drug, place
having test_measure>.99;
quit;
```

Does this achieve what I am trying to do, or am going about it all wrong?  Sorry if this is really trivial to most. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to calculate and estimate a percentile.  A simple way is to use `PROC SUMMARY`

```
proc summary data=have;
var score;
output out=pct p99=p99;
run;
```

This will create a data set named `pct` with a variable `p99` containing the 99th percentile.

Then filter your table for values `>=p99`

```
proc sql noprint;
create table want as
select a.*
    from have as a
    where a.score >= (select p99 from pct);
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you, and get the 99th percentile within each location and drug I would just add a "class place drug;" statement, correct?

Comment: Correct.  You would need to modify your query, obviously.